# How to do Backup and Restore in PostgreSQL database on Linux server

Tags: postgresql-10

I have a requirement of backup and restore PostgreSQL database from Dev server to QA server. Database size is 1TB.

Is there is any approach to restore directly from Dev server to QA server with out creating intermediate file?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgbasebackup.html

Answer (score 0):

Replicate Dev server data on QA server using the **pg_basebackup** command.

`pg_basebackup -h Dev_Server_host_name -D /QA_Server_Data_Directory/ -P -v`